# How to get a precise value for a Docker container's network usage

Tags: docker

For the project I'm working on, I need to be able to measure the total amount of network traffic for a specific container over a period of time. These periods of time generally are about 20 seconds, and the precision needed realistically is only in kilobytes. Ideally this solution would not involve the use of additional software either in the containers or on the host machine, and would be suitible for linux/windows hosts.

Originally I had planned to use the 'NET I/O' attribute of the 'docker stats' command, though the field is automatically formatted to a more human readable format (i.e. '200 MB') which means for containers that have been running for some time, I can't get the precision I need.

Is there any way to get the raw value of 'NET I/O' or to reset the running count? Outside of this I've explored using something tshark or iptables, but like I said above ideally the solution would not require additional programs. Though if there aren't any good solutions that fit that criteria any other suggestions would be welcome. Thank you!